# Disabling JS events

Tags: javascript, events, leaflet

I'm using maps on my webpage and I have the following JS code:

```
map.on('zoomend', function() {
   populate();
});
```

When i zoom over the map, the function populate() is called (it's used to put some markers on the map).

What I want is to disable the event 'zoomend' while populate is doing its stuff, so I would like something like this:

```
map.on('zoomend', function() {
   // DISABLE ZOOMEND EVENT 
   populate();
   // ENABLE ZOOMEND AGAIN
});
```

How could I do this?

Thank you!

EDIT: here is a piece of my function populate()

```
function populate() {
    $.post('/LoadMarkersServlet', {
       lat_min: map.getBounds().getNorthWest(),
       lat_max: map.getBounds().getSouthEast(),
       //more parameters
       //...
    }, function (responseText) {
       if(responseText !== null) {
           var p = JSON.parse(responseText);

           for(var i=0; i<p.length; i++){
               // here I read the responseText and put markers where it says
           }
           map.addLayer(markers);
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded, so doing this would do nothing since `populate()` is already blocking the thread at that point. Now if `populate()` kicks off some asynchronous requests for data or something, then the `// ENABLE AGAIN ZOOMEND` would need to be elsewhere when all those asynchronous callbacks have been resolved.

Comment: Yes, @PatrickRoberts, I just want to prevent the user do populate again while the JS is populating the map. When the populate function has finished, user can launch popultare again using zoom.

Comment: The re-enabling would need to be placed in code that you don't even have shown currently.

Comment: In function populate I'm calling to a servlet using AJAX and writing the response. Where would you write the code? And, more important... what code?

Comment: if you share at least pseudocode for your `populate()` definition, I'll provide an adequate answer that should work.

Comment: By the way, am I to assume this is leaflet.js?

Comment: Yes, I'm using leaflet. There's the code for populate function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
// name your event listener
map.on('zoomend', function handleZoomEnd() {
  // turn it off temporarily
  map.off('zoomend', handleZoomEnd);
  // pass a function to re-enable it after ajax completes
  populate(function () {
    map.on('zoomend', handleZoomEnd);
  });
});

// accept callback function as parameter
function populate(cb) {
    $.post('/LoadMarkersServlet', {
       lat_min: map.getBounds().getNorthWest(),
       lat_max: map.getBounds().getSouthEast(),
       //more parameters
       //...
    }, function (responseText) {
       if(responseText !== null) {
           var p = JSON.parse(responseText);

           for(var i=0; i<p.length; i++){
               // here I read the responseText and put markers where it says
           }
           map.addLayer(markers);

           // this re-enables zoomend callback
           cb();
       }
    });
}
```